# Is there a way to paste a local image on abbreviation with AutoKey in Python?

Tags: python, autokey

AutoKey allows abbreviations to expand into text, and even emojis. However, I was wondering if there was a way for me to paste an image on a keyboard abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently. The underlying code just saves abbreviation expansions as a string.

However, if you wanted to do this, you could create a custom python script that loads the image into the clipboard then sends a paste signal. Check the Autokey docs for how to create and run custom scripts.

Of course, this would only work if the place you paste the image supports image input, e.g., OpenOffice.